# Django - Optimize queries with select_related()

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-select-related

I have the following model.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Driver')

class Country(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Driver(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country')
```

I want to select the name of drivers owning a car.

```
Car.objects.all().values('owner__name')
```

Do I need to use select_related() method, to avoid a join for each object, or it is redundant because implicit with values() method?

```
Car.objects.all().select_related('owner').values('owner__name')
```

In the same way, I want, this time, the name of countries with drivers owning a car. Which one is the best?

```
Car.objects.all().values('owner__country__name')
Car.objects.all().select_related('owner', 'country').values('owner__country__name')
Car.objects.all().select_related('owner__country').values('owner__country__name')
```

Comment: The last part I assume you want `Driver.objects.filter(car__isnull=False,...)` but your question is a bit broad, you should limit it down to the first question about implicit joins

Comment: Thanks, I edit the question to reduce the scope to the use of select_related().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, all the occurrences of `.all()` in your examples can be deleted; the manager (`.objects`) already has almost all methods of the QuerySet, except for `.delete()`.

`.select_related` is only helpful when your eventual query returns *model instances*; then, all the foreign key of each instance will be pre-loaded.

But if you are using `.values` you are getting dictionaries, and there are no foreign key attributes to pre-load. So it should not be used in that case.

When you do `.values('owner__name')` Django already sees that it needs to join owners and cars, no extra queries are done.

In the last one you want Countries, so use Country.objects:

```
Country.objects.filter(driver__car__isnull=False).values('name')
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. But even with a dict we can imagine that to iterate on each element, Django can made a new join query in the database. This is why I would like to be sure that select related not usefull in this case.